# Postman: Using JSON to create dynamic data

Tags: json, postman, postman-collection-runner

I have JSON script to enter data in the Web DB, Below:

{
  "email_address": "test@gmail.com",
  "first_nm": "test",
  "last_nm": "test",
  "birth_dt": "1974-01-27",
  "address_line_1": "",
  "address_line_2": "",
  "city": "Dallas",
  "state": "TX",
  "zip": "75206",
  "phone_no": "214-235-4948",
  "store_id": "1001",
  "gender_cd": "F",
  "visit_frequency": "RN",
  "visit_type": "DN,LU",
  "favorite_dish": "CK,SH,ST",
  "favorite_beverage": "CT,WN",
  "favorite_dining": "FM,DN,HH",
  "source_cd": "PD"
}

I want to be be able to run this in a app like postman where the Email Address, First and last name will change on each post. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using variables in postman?
Read more here: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/intro_to_environments_and_globals

After reading the above link, you'll see that we can make use of the `Pre-Request`scripts in postman to dynamically set the values of these variables.

In your request body you can put the JSON along with the values inside the JSON that are meant to be dynamically changed, replace those with variables.
For eg:

```
{
    "email_address": "{{email_address}}",
    "first_nm": "{{first_name}}",
    "last_nm": "{{last_nm}}",
    "birth_dt": "{{dob}}",
    "address_line_1": "{{address1}}",
    "address_line_2": "{{address1}}",
    "city": "{{city}}",
    "state": "{{state}}",
    ...
}
```

Now you can make use of the environment / global variables in Postman and change the values through scripts / manually change the values.

You can import the following collection *(Click on Import > Import from Link)* in your Postman app and I've laid out a basic example for you to get started with.
Check the pre-request script and body of the `Sample Post Request`
: https://www.getpostman.com/collections/231c5ff4830e5b7b9d9d

Here's an official tutorial video by the Postman Team on how you can use variables: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTOS_dFeXvM

Comment: Since you'll be using the collection runner, you can move your JSON to a data file and use that in the runner. This post explains it well: http://blog.getpostman.com/2018/04/11/looping-through-a-data-file-in-the-postman-collection-runner/